# Jquery append subtleties in IE8 and below

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have the following code:

```
var editLink = $('<a href=# class="edit" id="edit">').append('edit')
```

It doesn't work in IE8 and below, which creates nothing at all when I use editLink later on.

This does work:

```
var editLink = $('<a href=# class="edit" id="edit">edit</a>')
```

However I have a lot of nested attributes to put in, and don't really want a very long piece of HTML in the middle of the jQuery.

Any ideas why the first version doesn't work?

Comment: The 1st version doesn't work because IE 8 has a lot of random quirks.  Things can just not work for seemingly no reason.  P.S. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I notice that you have no quotes around `#` in your href. You could also do `$('<a>edit</a>').attr( "href", "#" ).attr( "class", "edit" ).attr(....)` I think? Those chained methods can be on new lines for added clearity.

Comment: @Sumurai8: You can even do `$('<a></a>', { text: 'edit', href: '#', class: 'edit', ...})`.  You can pass an object as the 2nd parameter to `$()` and it'll set those as the properties.  You can use either `text:` or `html:` depending on what you want in the element.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thanks. I was not aware that `$` accepted a second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.

It's simply that the element being created needs to be closed. ie

```
var editLink = $('<a href=# class="edit" id="edit"></a>').append('edit');
```

I had been worried that this would append the text **after** the element, rather than inside it, however of course append means add to the end of the inside of the targeted element.

So this works perfectly.  With fields that don't have closing tags, like,

```
<input type=text>
```

and so on, you don't need to have the closing element.